# CS50 (Pset4) Filter more "edges" code went wrong

Tags: c, cs50

I made first the code for the middle pixel but it doesn't work correctly I don't know why. I don't know if the code has something missing or I misunderstood the algorithm?

The code for middle pixels :

```
  RGBTRIPLE edge[height][width];

  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      edge[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
      edge[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
      edge[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
    }
  }

  for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
      int red1 = (edge[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1)
          + (edge[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) + (edge[h][w - 1].rgbtRed * -2)
          + (edge[h][w + 1].rgbtRed * 2) + (edge[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1)
          + (edge[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * 1);
      int red2 = (edge[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1)
          + (edge[h - 1][w].rgbtRed * -2) + (edge[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed * -1)
          + (edge[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (edge[h + 1][w].rgbtRed * 2)
          + (edge[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed);

      int g_red = round(pow(red1 * red1 + red2 * red2, 0.5));
      if (g_red > 255)
        g_red = 255;
      image[h][w].rgbtRed = g_red;

      int blue1 = edge[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1 + edge[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue
          + edge[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -2 + edge[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue * 2
          + edge[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1 + edge[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue;
      int blue2 = edge[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue * -1
          + edge[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue * -2 + edge[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue * -1
          + edge[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue + edge[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue * 2
          + edge[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue;

      int g_blue = round(sqrt(blue1 * blue1 + blue2 * blue2));
      if (g_blue > 255)
        g_blue = 255;
      image[h][w].rgbtRed = g_blue;

      int green1 = edge[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1
          + edge[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen + edge[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -2
          + edge[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen * 2 + edge[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1
          + edge[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen;
      int green2 = edge[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen * -1
          + edge[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen * -2 + edge[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen * -1
          + edge[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen + edge[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen * 2
          + edge[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen;

      int g_green = round(sqrt(green1 * green1 + green2 * green2));
      if (g_green > 255)
        g_green = 255;
      image[h][w].rgbtRed = g_green;

    }
  }
```

The check 50 outputs :
:( edges correctly filters middle pixel
expected "210 150 60\n", not "150 40 100\n"

Comment: I don't get why you are weighting the values from different neighbour pixels and taking square root. The CS50 codes posted here usually just find the simple average of each r,g,b, component. At the edges and corners, you also count the number of on-map pixels to use as a divisor.

Comment: @WeatherVane this is probably not the blurring task but the edge detection using Sobel operator.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't understand you .I used the kernels that they told us to use

Comment: as explained by Gerhardh

Comment: @WeatherVane ok thank you and Gerhard i will google more to understand it

Comment: @WeatherVane  gxRed =   (float)((-1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (0 * imgCopy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) +
                              (-2 * imgCopy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed)     + (0 * imgCopy[h][w].rgbtRed)     + (2 * imgCopy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed) +
                              (-1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) + (0 * imgCopy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed) + (1 * imgCopy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed));   
I wrote it like that but same results . this code for middle pixels only and don't work

Comment: I recommend to post a 4x4 example that is a [mcve].

Comment: @MohamadMmdouh Is your `int` 16 bit or 32 bit? (Concern about overflow with `blue1 * blue1`)

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem:

**Accessing arrays outside their range**

Example: on first iteration, code attempts to access `edge[-1][-1]`.
This is not "code for middle pixels" only.

```
for(int h = 0 ; h < height ; h ++) {
    for(int w = 0 ; w < width ; w ++) {
       int red1 = (edge[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed * -1) + ...
```

Code needs re-write to handle edge and corner cases.

---

**Questionable algorithm**

It is unclear how accessing 6 of a pixels 8 neighbors uniformly detects an edge.

I'd expect a `/6` someplace to keep `image[][]` on same magnitude of `edge[][]`.

Comment: I made it for middle pixels only but it doesn't work . it suppose to access to 6 pixels around it according to the kernels

Comment: I made it for middle pixels only --> No. the posted code also operates on the corner/edge pixels.  It does so in a way that invokes _undeifned behavior_.  For now, try `for(int h = 1 ; h + 1 < height ; h ++)` and like-wise for `width`  to operate only on _middle pixels_.

Comment: "according to the kernels" is unclear.  Post a link to the documentation describing the algorithm.